# Using OpenCSV to write in a column instead of row

Tags: java, csv, text, io, opencsv

I have a 1 dimension array  `String[]` that I want to write to a CSV file, and then view in a spreadsheet program such as Excel. However, the size/length of this array is too big to fit in the number of allowed columns, but is small enough to fit in the number of allowed rows.

So, how do I write column-wise instead of row-wise?

The current code that I'm using:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) [
        CSVWriter writer2 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("testing.csv"), '\t');

        String[] string = new String[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            string[i] = "Testing";
        }

        writer2.writeNext(string); //  !!EXPORTS AS ROW AND NOT A COLUMN!! //
        writer2.close();




    }
}
```

Comment: @ppeterka 66 Why did you change the code in my question

Comment: Sorry, wasn't intentional... When still editing my answer, I must have accidentally clicked on the wrong edit button... I reverted it back.

Answer (score 1):

To write a `String[]` to a file, each string in separate lines, you don't need a CSVWriter... Plain old [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29) will do

```
public static class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    String[] strings = new String[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      strings[i] = "Testing";
    }

    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("testing.csv");
    try {
      for (String s : strings) {
        output.write(s.getBytes("UTF-8")); // don't rely on default encoding!
      }
    }
    finally {
      output.close();
    }
  }
}
```

However, if you really want to write using `CSVWriter`:

```
public static class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    CSVWriter writer2 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("testing.csv"), '\t');

    String[] strings = new String[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      strings[i] = "Testing";
    }

    String[] wrap = new String[1]; //probably saving on GC

    for (String s: strings) {
      wrap[0]=s;
      writer2.writeNext(wrap);
    }
    writer2.close();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[writeNext](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#writeNext%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) write 1 line.
If you call it twice, it will write 2 lines, if you call it 10 times it will then write 10 lines right? :)

EDIT: Okay, let's try this :

```
public void writeLines(String[] array, CSVWriter writer) {
    for (final String oneElement : array) {
        writer.writeNext(new String[] {oneElement});
    }
}
```

Now you can call the `writeLines` method to write a bunch of lines. If I take your example :

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CSVWriter writer2 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("testing.csv"), '\t');

        String[] string = new String[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            string[i] = "Testing";
        }

        writer2.writeLines(string); // This will write a column
        writer2.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does solve the problem for the toy example I provided, I'm looking for a method to write a column with as little fuss as it takes to write a row so it can be generalized to more complex problems.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a simple way to do something like `writer.writeColumn(...)`. These libraries are optimized to work on a line flow only. You will have to buffer your data creation (column add) and write everything (flush) once you have finished adding your colulmns.

Comment: I edited my example to show you how to write a column, but I'm not sure it's what you need